# Is there a relationship between the Arabic terms عائشة‎ (A'isha) and صلاة العشاء (isha prayer)?

Tags: arabic

There's two Arabic terms which overlap in transliteration:

- [A'isha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%27isha_(name)), a wife of the Prophet, written عائشة in Arabic.
- [Isha prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isha_prayer), the night-time daily prayer, written صلاة العشاء‎‎ in Arabic.

**Question**: Is there a relationship between the Arabic terms عائشة‎‎ (A'isha) and صلاة العشاء (isha prayer)?

My motivation for asking is just curiosity because "isha" is part of the word "A'isha" in the transliteration.

Comment: Isha is pronounced 'esha' an A'isha is pronounced I-Sha

Comment: Also, Isha means **Night** and Aisha means **she who lives**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no connection between the two words. The origin of the word 'ishā' (Arabic: عشاء) is 'asha (Arabic: عشا), which means poor vision. Night is called 'ishā' because vision deteriorates due to darkness (Source: Al-Mu'jam). The origin of the name 'A'isha (Arabic: عائشة) is 'āsh (Arabic: عاش), which means to live. The male equivalent name is 'Āyish (Arabic: عايش).